# More efficient way to modify and copy image files in terms of performance

Tags: python, for-loop

I've created a script which I run on GCP workbench. This code augments images (3 new img) for training a ML models and saves them in other bucket. Currently I'm running this code for 250k images so I end up with ~750k new images.

**Currently I'm running the augmentation and saving process in a 'for' loop. Is there a more efficient way to iterate over records in terms of performance? Can I somehow implement, for example, multithreading? Should I use some other construct than loop?**

```
from google.cloud import storage
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

def hash_to_blob(list_of_blobs):
    hash_blob = {}
    image_mime_types = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/bmp", "image/webp", "image/tiff"]
    
    # loop through all blobs and filter by content type
    for blob in list_of_blobs:
        if blob.content_type in image_mime_types:
            blobname = blob.name
            hashgroup = blobname.split('/')[-2]
            
            if hashgroup not in hash_blob:
                hash_blob[hashgroup] = []
            hash_blob[hashgroup].append(blob)
    return hash_blob


def main():
    # Define bucket and structure information
    raw_bucket = 'bucket1'
    project_id = 'project1'
    sub_folder = 'wp/train/'
    destination_bucket = 'bucket2'
    # Call client
    storage_client = storage.Client(project=project_id)
    print('Client storage loaded')
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(raw_bucket)
    destination_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(destination_bucket)
    print('Input bucket:')
    print(bucket)
    print('Output bucket')
    print(destination_bucket)
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=sub_folder)
    blobs_list = list(blobs)

    hash_blob_dict = hash_to_blob(blobs_list)

    # Define data augmentation functions
    data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
        layers.RandomRotation(0.1, fill_mode = 'nearest'),
        layers.RandomBrightness(0.1),
        layers.RandomContrast(0.1),
        layers.RandomCrop(224, 224)
    ])
    
    print('Data augmentation completed for:')

    for source_blob in hash_blob_dict.get('train'):
        # Transform blobl to img
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(source_blob.download_as_bytes()))
        # Resize to 256 256 for better cropping
        img = img.resize((256, 256))
        # Transform to tf.Tensor
        img_tf = tf.cast(tf.expand_dims(img, 0), tf.float32)
        # Get blob filename and metadata
        source_blob_name = os.path.basename(source_blob.name)
        meta_data = source_blob.metadata
        # Augment 3 images per each blob
        for i in range(3):
            # Augment image
            augmented_image = data_augmentation(img_tf)
            # Transform image from float tensor to uint8 numpy
            new_augmented_image = augmented_image.numpy().astype(np.uint8)[0]
            # Create new blob name
            new_blob_name = 'data-augmentation-crop-flip-rotate/train/' + source_blob_name[0:-4] + '_aug' + str(i) + '.png'
            # Create new blob in destination bucket
            destination_blob = destination_bucket.blob(new_blob_name)
            # Transform to image, load as byte format
            im = Image.fromarray(new_augmented_image)
            bs = BytesIO()
            im.save(bs, "png")
            # Upload new bloab to destination with metadata
            destination_blob.upload_from_string(bs.getvalue(), content_type = "image/png", num_retries = 10)
            destination_blob.metadata = meta_data
            destination_blob.patch()
            print(destination_blob)
       
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: As a general rule, use multithreading for I/O bound processing and multiprocessing for CPU-bound tasks